# update values in jquery based on angular change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

In my application I have used calendar widget using fullcalender.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#profile-calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: $scope.calendarEvent
    });
});
```

What I wanted to do is, I need to give different values to the event attribute based a angular event. the below code snippet is what I have used to update the `$scope.calendarEvent` attribute.

```
$scope.$on('profile_selection',function(event, args){
    $scope.calendarEvent = $rootScope.calendarEvent;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

But this is not working as I expected, the calendar is showing the initial value given to the `$scope.calendarEvent`. What should I do to make the `$scope.calendarEvent` take the changed value by the broadcast message and update dynamically.

Comment: Is your 'profile_selection' being called from somewhere, otherwise your approach seems correct. You can also use $timeout(function(){do something}, 0) instead of using $scope.$apply()

Comment: Why don't you use angular fullcalendar module ?

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal both profile_section and the jquery are in the same controller

Comment: No i meant $on is to listen to broadcast and emit events, so where are you firing those events. And if you add more code, it would be helpful

Comment: @CharlesRajendran Can you please create and share [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?